# How to change colour of event when click "book" button on fullcalendar

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to change the color of an event when a user clicks on "book" button. 
As default, the button is set to green, but wish for it to change to orange when clicked.

```
            $(' #eventBook').click(function () {
                var json = {
                    'Id': $('#eventBookId').val(),
                    'Title': $('#eventBookTitle').val(),
                    'Start': $('#eventBookStart').val(),
                    'End': $('#eventBookEnd').val(),
                    'AllDay': $('#eventBookAllDay').is(":checked") ? true : false,
                    'Description': $('#eventBookDescription').val(),
                    'Color': "Orange"//$('#eventBookColor').val()
                };

                console.log('Updating event json', json);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/TimeTable/BookEvent',
                    data: json,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        //refresh the calender
                        FetchEventsAndRenderCalendar();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Booking Could not be Saved');
                    }
                });
                // close Modal
                $('#eventModal').modal('hide');

            });
```

This is my service method to update the class within the database.

```
        public bool BookEvent(TimeTableEvent t)
        {
            var existing = db.TimeTableEvents.Where(a => a.Id == t.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existing != null)
            {
                existing.Title = t.Title;
                existing.Start = t.Start;
                existing.End = t.End;
                existing.Description = t.Description;
                existing.Color = "Orange";
                existing.AllDay = t.AllDay;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
document.getElementById("eventBook").style.color= "orange";
```

assuming that you want to change the text colour. Or backgroundcolor if you want to change the background colour.

Comment: When i add this within my javascript function the button itself is changing color to orange. However, I want it so if i click the button "book" the popup will disappear and the event on the calendar will have changed color to orange.

Any idea on how to overcome this?

Comment: Does the event have an Id attribute. if so, use that attribute instead of eventBook.